# Stop setInterval() without global variables

Tags: javascript

I am looking to start then later stop a setInterval, all examples that I've come across do this with a global variable, but I'd rather not use one if I can.

I have a button to start the setInterval and another to stop it. I can start it just fine, but I am unable to stop it without using a global variable.

This is what I have:

```
function counter() {
  function stop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(new Date());
  }, 1000);
  return stop;
}
$('#start').click(function() {
  counter();
});
$('#stop').click(function() {
  stop(); // this of course doesn't work
});
```

Comment: Use a block with `const` or `let`?

Comment: Right wrap the whole thing in an IIFE

Comment: you should move stop out of counter function so that it can be called inside $('stop').click(function() {})

Comment: It does not have to be a *global* variable, but a variable you have access to.

Comment: @user93 `stop` is `return`ed from there.

Comment: @Pointy With ES6, wouldn't a block be a good replacement for an IIFE? (If you use block-scoped declarations)

Comment: when you are calling the counter the timer starts and stop is returned but you are not storing it anywhere the returned value is just lost inside #start. A simple local variable should do the trick.

Comment: @AndrewLi yes I suppose so, though it might be a good idea to change the declaration of the `counter()` function to be a `let` assignment in that case.

Comment: You don't show one, so probably aren't using one, but *if* you are using a document ready handler then you already have a place to declare functions and variables that will not be global. Otherwise use an IIFE or ES6 block-scoped variable as already mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I think you require a static variable. But Unfortunately, javascript doesn't support static variables. However, we can create one. Because as in javascript functions are interpreted as objects so they could have static scope variable.

```js
function counter() {
    if (typeof counter.timer == 'undefined') {
        counter.timer = 0;
    }
    counter.timer = setInterval(function() {
        $("#output").text(new Date());
    }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(counter.timer);
}
$("#start").on('click', function() {
    counter();
});
$("#stop").on('click', function() {
    stop();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="start">start</button>
 <button type="button" id="stop">stop</button>
  <p id="output"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a global variable, but you can do it in many ways so here an approach, the HTML part:

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
```

and the JS part:

```
function timer() {
    var timer = null;
    function stop() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  function start() {
    timer  = setInterval(function(){
      console.log("repeat it");
    }, 500);    
  }

  return {
      stop,
    start
  };
}

var t = timer();

var startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
var stopBtn = document.getElementById("stop");

startBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    t.start();
}, false);

stopBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    t.stop();
}, false);
```

Here you have a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9tqsaxvf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the java-script Closures for this, change your codes to this :

```
function counter (action, tId) {
   var timer =setInterval(function() {  
    console.log(new Date());
 }, 1000);
 if(typeof tId!="undefined")
    window.clearInterval(tId);
   return function () {
    if(action=='stop'){
    counter('stop', timer)
   }
  }
 }

 $('#start').click(function() {
  counter('start');
 });
 $('#stop').click(function() {
   counter('stop'); 
 });
```

Actually what we do is to re-call the function with interval-id if action is stop.

Comment: I tested this and it did not work. It simply triggered another setInterval().

Comment: Well inside return function will pass the current Timer as a parameter to tId, it will clearInterval since tId is not undefined anymore.